# Why would I use ANOVA over the p-value to variable select missingness?

Tags: python, r, feature-selection, anova, p-value

If I create a variable that indicates missingness in a dataset.

What is the reason a professor would use ANOVA with chi squared to compare whether it is significant over just looking at the summary output and seeing that the p-value is the same?

Please let me know if I'm posting in the incorrect location.

This is the R code:

```
pima$missing <- apply(pima,1,anyNA) 
missingCasesMod <- glm(Outcome~missing,family = binomial, data = pima)
summary(missingCasesMod)
```

No idea how the p-value is calculated, however, when being specific.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! How would you calculate that p-value? How would the professor perform ANOVA?

Comment: @Dave It is done within R programming! Just a regular binary logistic model summary output. For ANOVA, there is a function called anova() within R. He used a chi squared test.

Comment: How is that p-value calculated in R?

Comment: @Dave

This is the R code:
pima$missing <- apply(pima,1,anyNA)
missingCasesMod <- glm(Outcome~missing,family = binomial, data = pima)
summary(missingCasesMod)

No idea how the p-value is calculated, however, when being specific.

Comment: Please add the new info in comments as an edit to the post. We want posts to be self-contained, and few people actually reads comments. Also, comments can be deleted.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen thank you!